Cannot access to local devices when the connection to the internet is interrupted
Need a hint as I am running out of ideas to progress in my project:
I have two phones: a Pixel 6a / Android 14 and an old Huawei / Android 9. I have a network with an Access Point for WiFi connections of PCs and Smartphones and a gateway to the internet. All works fine, PCs and smartphones can access devices in the local network as well as the internet.
When the connection to the internet goes down:

PCs can no longer access sites in the internet (obviously), but can access devices in the local network via browser specifying the local IP address (all devices are in the same subnet) – either with LAN connection or WiFi connection.
Smartphones, however, cannot access devices in the local network …. joining the WiFi network is successful (it states no internet access, which I know and don’t need now) but when specifying a local IP address in the browser the connection times out.

It's clear that the phone switches to cellular if the web connection of the WiFi gateway is down. However, I do not intend to connect to the web but want to connect to local devices through a browser specifying the local IP address while the connection to the web is down (for connecting to local devices I don't need the web connection). Accessing local devices is working fine while the web connection is up but times out when the connection to the web is down.
What setting on the smartphone might be wrong or missing that prevents access to local devices when the connection to the internet is interrupted?

What Android version is installed and what device model do you use? Is the cellular data connection active in the smartphone? If yes then Android can switch to cellular data if the WiFi looses Internet connection. Newer Android versions can keep connection to the WiFi but older Android versions will completely switch to cellular data.

Thanks Robert, Have two phones: a Pixel 6a / Android 14 and an old Huawei / Android 9. It's clear that the phone switches to cellular if the web connection of the WiFi gateway is down. However I do not intend to connect to the web but want to connect to local devices through a browser specifying the local IP address while the connection to the web is down (for connecting to local devices I don't need the web connection). Accessing local devices is working fine while the web connection is up but times out when the connection to the web is down.

Seems that it's because the network routing configuration prevent you for connecting to it.
You can use a shell on your phone to verify that, with adb shell or ConnectBot. After issuing ip -4 route show table all and ip rule, you can see routes to the modem interface and rules that redirect packets to respective routing table.
If you has root access in your phone, you can change ip configuration by hand, enter the shell and try adding a route in the same table that has the default route pointing to internet. Add something like ip -4 route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 and try accessing your device on 192.168.1.0/24 network, assuming it is your local network and wlan0 is the wifi interface of phone.
Its pretty annoying for my specific use case, because i wanted to give support to my family network when they have no internet over wifi, i can connect to VNC server on phone via VPN on mobile internet and control the phone, but i can't control local devices connected to the same wifi, and i needed to configure these local devices to get wifi internet working again, among other things.

It seems perfectly reasonable to me that the software on the mobile has been written to not let the browser run if there is no internet.  Note the stress on "mobile"  While the mobile will can use data from Wifi, the browsers are a different story.
I had a quick look, I can't find any setting to help you.

Thanks Rohit, the part I’d like to understand is why

I can access from a smartphone to a local device through the browser specifying a local IP address via the WiFi network while the gateway does have a live connection to the internet (same subnet, all functions work fine) while
I canNOT access from a smartphone to a local device through the browser specifying a local IP address via the WiFi network while the gateway does NOT have a live connection to the internet (identical setup as above, only difference is connection to the internet is interrupted).


The internet is not needed or used to reach a local device in the same subnet, thus why is a live connection to the internet necessary?
It works fine from a PC under Windows …. with live access to the internet AND WITHOUT live access to the internet I can reach and use all functions on a local device.

The only difference is indeed the live connection to the internet, which is not needed to access a local device from a smartphone in the same subnet …..  this makes me narrow down the potential cause to be in a setting on the smartphone / Android – however which setting as there is not much I can set (on a PC I can set the network properties  …..  is there a way I can set these in Android?)
